# Calculate the volume $y= x^2+2$ and $y=3$

Tags: calculus, volume

The area enclosed between $y=x^2+2$ and $y=3$ is revolved about the horizontal line $y=3$  to form a solid. Calculate the volume. (Hint: Disks)[image]

The only part that i'm confused on is how to calculate the radius. could someone explain how I would go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the radius of each disk is the distance between $y=3$ and $y=x^2+2$, or  $1-x^2$.

For the radius, it is just the distance between the curves, so subtract :)

You are integrating between intersections, or $-1$ and $1$.

So, you have $\displaystyle π\int_{-1}^{1}(1-x^2)^2\,dx$.

Remember simply, that you are stacking circles on each other, you just need to know the radius, and apply $πr^2$. And as you stack each of the circles, you get an integral :)

P.S., this is not required, but if you notice that the solid formed will be symmetrical if divided by the plane $x=0$, you can rewrite the integral to $\displaystyle 2π\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^2)^2\,dx$.

This will make subtraction simpler if you need to do this by hand.

Comment: Interesting, my only other question, I thought I would be intergrating from  -1 to 1. Wouldn't we take 3 = x^2 + 2, minus 2 on each side, then take the square root of 1? which would give +1 and -1. Thank you for your clarification thus far, just trying to get an understanding!

Comment: we are integrating from -1 to 1, i just misread the question. i edited it :)